# UIWebView loadRequest exc_bad_access

Tags: ios, uiwebview, exc-bad-access

I have an app. Does nothing else, only loads this site: `http://www.weact.ch`. But sometimes it crashes. Get an exc_bad_access. Any idea why? The only what can be a lead, call is in `NSXPCConnection.m-user.apple.nsurlstorage-cache`

and here is the code, the one-line-app:

```
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL:  NSURL(string: "http://www.weact.ch")))
```

[image]

and an other crash:

[image]

Comment: check this post. U will get somewhere. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796041/the-connection-to-service-named-com-apple-nsurlstorage-cache-was-invalidated

And also try all basic methods like deleting derived data in xcode folder, restarting xcode,resetting simulator etc.

Comment: have u implemented delegate methods of webview.Try implementing all delegate methods such as didfinishLoading & didfailWithError u will come to know the error.

Comment: implemented but it is an exc_bad_access

Comment: Posting the relevant code from your app would be helpful. Also, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264727/uiwebview-exc-bad-access-crash?rq=1